# how execute a function to return the executed in string

Tags: javascript, prototype

good, I'm just starting in javascript, you could do this:
execute:

```
x ('y'). z (). b ('c')
```

and that has as output:

```
x y
z
b c
```

I've been testing with prototype but they are left in the first part

```
Object.prototype.getNameOfCall = function (fn) {
var e = fn.arguments [0]
     for (var p in this)
         if (this [p] === fn)
             return p + '' + e;
     throw "Callback not in object.";
};

x = function (y) {
     console.log (this.getNameOfCall (arguments.callee)); // MyClass
console.log (this.getOwnPropertyNames)
};

x ('y')
```

I do not know if I'm on the right track, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear why you want this, but you can reflect on the function being called:

```js
function x () {
  console.log(`${arguments.callee.name} ${[].join.call(arguments, ' ')}`)
}

x('y', 'z')
```

You'd have to add that line to every function you want to log in this way.